# UI freezes when I login and navigate to new screen. The screen works once I refresh the app. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've building a React Native app and using redux and have implemented the React-Navigation.  I have a couple off issues I'm working through and below is one of them that might be able to tackle both problems.

My screen flow is supposed to look like this:

1. Login (via Facebook)
2. Dashboard (via automatic re-direct using React-Navigation)

While this flow works, I'm finding that once I land on the Dashboard, the screen is frozen.  If I restart the app, the app does work as intended (i.e. it makes a firebase call to retrieve my credentials, and automatically redirects from the Login screen to the Dashboard).  The Dashboard then accepts all touches and the UI works fine.

Any idea what might be going?  I feel like the issue is with how I'm setting up my listeners.  I've implemented my navigation into redux as well.  I've pulled out the relevant code below, but you can find the full code in the github links as well.

## .src/actions/actions.js

([github link:  actions.js](https://github.com/deepanjan1/rtc-react-native/blob/master/src/actions/actions.js))

```
// User Stuff
export const watchUserData = () => (
  (dispatch) => {
    currentUserListener((user) => {
      // if (user !== null) {
      if (user) {
        console.log('from action creator login: ' + user.displayName);
        dispatch(loadUser(user));
        dispatch(watchReminderData(user.uid));  //listener to pull reminder data
        dispatch(watchContactData(user.uid));  //listener to pull contact data
        dispatch(watchPermissions(user.uid));  //listener to pull notificationToken
      } else {
        console.log('from action creator: ' + user);
        dispatch(removeUser(user));
        dispatch(logOutUser(false));
        dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }));
      }
    });
  }
);

export const watchUserDataForLogin = () => (
  (dispatch) => {
    currentUserListener((user) => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(user)) {
        dispatch(loadUser(user));
        dispatch(setLoggedInUser(true));
        dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Dashboard' }));
      }
    });
  }
);
```

## .src/screens/Login.js

[github link: Login.js](https://github.com/deepanjan1/rtc-react-native/blob/master/src/screens/Login.js)

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener = currentUserListener((snapshot) => {
      try {
        this.props.watchUserDataForLogin();
      } catch (e) {
        this.setState({ error: e, });
      }
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    if (this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener) {
      this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener();
    }
  };
```

## .src/screens/Dashboard.js

[github link:  Dashboard.js](https://github.com/deepanjan1/rtc-react-native/blob/master/src/screens/Dashboard.js)

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    // Listener that loads the user, reminders, contacts, and notification data
    // this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener = currentUserListener((snapshot) => {
    //   try {
    //     this.props.watchUserData();
    //   } catch (e) {
    //     this.setState({ error: e, });
    //   }
    // });
    this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener = this.props.watchUserData();
  };
```

Let me know if you need additional information.  Was trying to keep it succinct, but can add more details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what was going on.  I had set up the listener incorrectly and so I couldn't unsubscribe from it once I left the login screen.  The code now looks like this:

## src/screen/Login.js

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener = this.props.watchUserDataForLogin();
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    if (this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener) {
      this.unsubscribeCurrentUserListener();
    }
  };
```